# git citool doesn't work

Tags: xcode, git, macos

I installed xCode on my mac, and now git citool doesn't work. All the rest of the git functions work properly, but when running git citool, I get the message:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-citool: line 15: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-gui/lib/Git Gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish: No such file or directory
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-citool: line 15: exec: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/share/git-gui/lib/Git Gui.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Is there something I forgot to install?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the very late reply, I found this question via Google search. At this point, my answer is more for anyone who may still be having this problem (or if I happen to forget this solution in the future).

There's an informative bug report (this very issue) at Google Code for the git os x installer project: https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/issues/detail?id=41.

In summary, you should download and install the activetcl package from activestate (http://www.activestate.com/activetcl/downloads). Restart your terminal session, and the error should go away.

Comment: I still have this problem, I've been working with silly workarounds for months now. I'll give it a try and let you know. Many thanks!